# ¿Como puedo recorrer un array de json y obtener sus valores para mostrarlos en la vista?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

Mi método para acceder a un url del json es el siguiente y funciona, pero ahora quiero recorrer el json con un for y su ´.lenght´ pero no pude.

El json del cual quiero obtener las url es el siguiente

http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=74fa8799c027f3af0b2faf44ac1c9e47

```
<scriptsrc="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js</scr>
<div id="success">
<div id="artisturl"></div>
</div>

$.ajax({
   type : 'GET',
   url : 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search',
   data : {'q':'coldplay',
   'type':'artist'
   },
   dataType : 'json',
   success : function(data) {
      $('#success #artisturl').html(data.artists.items[0].uri) ;
   },
}) ;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

¿Y por qué usar jQuery cuando puedes usar JavaScript nativo?
Aquí hay una solución que no requiere de librerías externas:

```
for(let i = 0; i < data.artists.items.length; i++) {
    console.log(data.artists.items[i].href);  // (o el campo que necesites)
}
```

Sé que ya estás usando jQuery, pero soy partidario de usar siempre que se pueda las herramientas nativas (aunque entiendo que vaya en gustos). Personalmente, no me parece más complejo que la solución con jQuery, y así eres más consciente de tu código.

Por cierto, no hace falta que parsees el JSON, ya que `data` ya es un objeto.

Comment: Muchas muchas gracias me quedo mucho mas claro y probe eso y me funciono a la perfeccion, voy hacer con javascript puro el buscador ya que puedo seguir el for dentro de otro for con los .each dentro de otro .each me pierdo un poco ja

Answer (score 10):

Puede hacer con each propio de jquery :

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    console.log(item);
});
```

Por ejemplo desde este link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342371/jquery-loop-on-json-data-using-each

Comment: Pero para usar ese metodo, debo parsear al json? Json.parse() ? porque despues de parserlo podria mostrar los resultados?o estoy confundiendo creo

Comment: directamente lo utilizas así, no debes parsearlo de eso se encarga el `$.each`