# Como llamar un api con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, api

Debo realizar un `Landingpage`, y en este debo incluir 4 lineas de 5 productos de un API.

¿Como hago para llamar ese API desde `JavaScript` y como hago para que solo me ponga 4 lineas de 5 productos?.

Tengo una pagina que es un API, y que contiene unos productos con categorías, id del producto.... es esto lo que contiene

```
[  
   {  
      "dataBasic":{  
         "id":"33",
         "productoId":"2646"
      },
      "dataComplete":[  
         {  
            "id":"2646",
            "referencia":"102 -2119",
            "descripcion":"Enterizo Levantacola Capellini",
            "en_descripcion":"Enterizo Levantacola Capellini",
            "es_url":null,
            "en_url":null,
            "marca":"1",
            "precioAlDetal":"89.90",
            "precioPorPaquete":"44.49",
            "precioPorMayor":"44.49",
            "precioTienda":"64.40",
            "precioMiscelaneo":"48.00",
            "precioOutlet":null,
            "proveedor":"2",
            "publicar":"Si",
            "publicarOferta":"Si",
            "publicarEnTienda3":null,
            "publicarEnTienda4":null,
            "publicarEnTienda5":null,
            "descripcion_long_es":null,
            "descripcion_long_en":null,
            "categoriaId":"21",
            "nom_marca":"Capellini",
            "cod_proveedor":"102",
            "nom_proveedor":"CAPOHEIRA"
         }
      ],
```

Lo que necesito es que estos datos me los muestre un  `html con su respectiva imagen` y con unos estilos aplicados en css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo uso una clase `API` basada en `JQuery` para trabajar con todo lo relacionado con la `api`. Dependiendo de la `api` a usar el `token` tendra un funcionamiento distinto, en mi caso mi `API` usa el token mediante un `Header` de la `petición HTTP`

```
    var api; // Variable api global para todos los .js
    class Api {
        // Se usa el constructor para crear nuestra api con la url correcta
        constructor(host, port, protocol, token) {
            this.host = host;
            this.port = port;
            this.protocol = protocol;
            this.token = token;
            this.baseUrl = protocol + host + ":" + port + "/";
            this.result = undefined;
            this.req = undefined;
        };
// Creamos las funciones GET, POST y les asignamos un succes CallOut para recuperar los datos de la peticion
        Get(req, async) {
            this.req = req;
//Creamos una peticion ajax usando jQuery, aqui deberias de crear la petición usando los parámetros que necessites para tu API
                $.ajax({ async: async, type:'get', url: this.baseUrl + req, headers: {
                    "token": this.token
                }, success: successCallOut, error: function(xhr,status,error){
                    console.log("-----------Error Api GET " + this.baseUrl + req + "------------------");
                    console.log("Status: " + status);
                    console.log("Error :" + error);
                    console.log(xhr);
                    console.log("---------------End Error----------------");
                    this.result = "error";
                }});
                if(!async){
                    while (this.result == undefined) {}
                    return this.result;
                }
            };
            GetSync(req){
                return this.Get(req, false);
            };
            GetAsync(req){
                return this.Get(req, true);
            };
            Post(req, body, bodyType, async) {
                this.req = req;
                $.ajax({ async: async, type:'post', url: this.baseUrl + req, data: body, contentType: bodyType, headers: {
                    "token": this.token
                }, success: successCallOut, error: function(xhr,status,error){
                    console.log("-----------Error Api POST " + api.baseUrl + req + "------------------");
                    console.log("Body: \"" + bodyType + "\" " + body);
                    console.log("Status: " + status);
                    console.log("Error: " + error);
                    console.log(xhr);
                    console.log("---------------End Error----------------");
                    this.result = "error";
                }});
                if(!async){
                    while (this.result == undefined) {}
                    return this.result;
                }
            }
            PostJson(req, body, async){
                return this.Post(req, body, "application/json", async);
            }
            PostJsonSync(req, body){
                return this.Post(req, body, "application/json", false);
            }
            PostJsonAsync(req, body){
                return this.Post(req, body, "application/json", true);
            }
            SetToken(req){
                $.ajax({ async: false, type:'get', url: this.baseUrl + req,
                 success: tokenCallOut, error: function(xhr,status,error){
                    console.log("-----------Error Api GET " + this.baseUrl + req + "------------------");
                    console.log("Status: " + status);
                    console.log("Error :" + error);
                    console.log(xhr);
                    console.log("---------------End Error----------------");
                    this.token = "error";
                }});
            }
        };
        function tokenCallOut(data){
            console.log("API TOKEN SUCCESS");
            api.token = data;
        }
        // Aqui es donde trabajaremos con los resultados de la petición, por ejemplo tu haces la peticion a /productos y la redirijes a la funcion ProcesarProductos(), mi ejemplo es /news/last
        function successCallOut(data){
            console.log("API GET/POST SUCCESS");
            api.result = data;
            switch (api.req){
                case "auth":
                    alert(data['token']);
                    break;
                case "handle":
                    alert(data);
                    break;
                case "news/last":
                    ShowLastNews();
                    break;
            }
        };

    function ShowLastNews() {
        //Recuperamos el resultado de la peticion
        var news = api.result;
        //Mostramos el resultado de la petición
        console.log(news);
        //Aqui és donde tienes que hacer los GetElementById() y assignarles el contenido de la petición
    }
```

Más información de `AJAX` con `JQuery`
http://librosweb.es/libro/fundamentos_jquery/capitulo_7/metodos_ajax_de_jquery.html

Para trabajar con esta clase és muy fácil solo necessitas llamar a la funcion `GET` de la clase

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = IndexLoadCode;
        function IndexLoadCode() {
            api = new Api('localhost','3000','http://','');
            api.SetToken('auth?user=main');
            api.GetSync('news/last');
        }
    </script>
```

Lo cual devuelve el siguiente resultado
[image: resultado]

en mi caso como la peticion que devuelve la api ya la devuelve como JSON me llega directamente el objeto como JSON y no necessito el JSON.Parse()
[image: api.result]

Para añadir el contenido a los elementos és así de simple

```
$(#id).html(api.result.contenido);
```

También lo puedes añadir creando elementos `DOM`

[Crear elementos del DOM con jQuery](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/40754/crear-elementos-del-dom-con-jquery)

Para añadir css

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_addclass.asp

Para cambiar la imagen usa attr
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_attr.asp

```
$(#img).attr('src',api.result.src);
```

Información extra de como trabajar con JSON

[Recorrer JSON con JQuery](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/67500/recorrer-json-con-jquery)

[¿Como puedo recorrer un array de json y obtener sus valores para mostrarlos en la vista?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8402/como-puedo-recorrer-un-array-de-json-y-obtener-sus-valores-para-mostrarlos-en-l)

Espero no haberme dejado nada y que te sirva de ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Bueno aqui una forma de hacerlo. Imaginemos que el API me retorna lo siguiente:

```
{
 'username': 'Einer',
 'profileImg' : 'https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-kdXug2D99gg/V8lWesUS0nI/AAAAAAAADcA/5a2fTm3mTkwwrlO-RpzXM7SZ9ydTSpqzQCLcB/s320/cool-boys-kid-style-whatsapp-dp-profiledp.jpg'
};
```

Solo tendriamos que hacer lo siguiente:

```
<div id="contenedor">
  </div>
function presentarUsuario()
{
   var responseAPI = {
     'username': 'Einer',
     'profileImg' : 'https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-kdXug2D99gg/V8lWesUS0nI/AAAAAAAADcA/5a2fTm3mTkwwrlO-RpzXM7SZ9ydTSpqzQCLcB/s320/cool-boys-kid-style-whatsapp-dp-profiledp.jpg'
    };

  var info = '<div class="user-info">' +
      '<img src="' + responseAPI.profileImg + '" />' +
  "<div class='username'>" + responseAPI.username + "</div>" +

'</div>';

  document.getElementById("contenedor").innerHTML = info;
}
```

Aqui el css:

```
 .user-info{
    background:white;
    border:solid 1px #ccc;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #ccc;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#000;
    }

.user-info img{
  width:30px;
  display:inline;
}
.username{
    position: absolute;
    top: 47px;
    font-size: 19px;
  left: 41px;
}
.user-info:hover{
 background:#f9f9f9
}
```

Ejemplo en [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/vunevuhayo/edit?html,css,js,output).

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar Ajax para hacer el request al API y tomar el response sin importar la cantidad de elementos que retorne.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery.support.cors = true;

    $.ajax(
     {
         type: "GET",
         url: 'http://myapi:port/',
         data: { get_param: 'name' },
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         cache: false,
         success: function (data) {
             var trHTML = '';
             $.each(data, function (i, element) {
                  trHTML += '<tr><td>' + element.name + '</td><td>';
             });
             /* #product es el nombre de una tabla, pero puedes utilizar cualquier contenedor html*/
             $('#product').append(trHTML);
         },

         error: function (msg) {

             trHTML += msg.responseText;
         }
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Veo que es una pregunta de hace bastante tiempo ya pero bueno por ahí le puede servir a alguno. Si bien ya hay una respuesta que ha servido al propósito, no soy muy partidario de usar jQuery ya que podemos lograr lo mismo con [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) o axios (librería) de manera más simple.

En el caso a la que la pregunta se refiere y, tomando como ejemplo una API de localización, podríamos hacer algo como:

```js
// API URL
const url = 'https://ipapi.co/json/';

// Establecemos una función asíncrona para el fetch con el parámetro de la url de la API.
async function fetchAPI(apiURL) {
  let response = await fetch(url);
  let data = await response.json();
  return data;
}

// Llamamos a la funcion
fetchAPI(url).then(data => {
  // Ya dentro, podemos trabajar los datos
  console.log('Tu IP es: ', data.ip)
  console.log('Tu ciudad es: ', data.city);
  console.log('Toda la info: ', data);
}).catch(error => {console.log(error)});//en caso de algún error
```

Mas info sobre fetch [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await).

Espero que sirva, saludos!

Comment: Tampoco soy partidario de usar jQuery teniendo otras soluciones ahora en el mercado. No estoy de acuerdo con el uso de fetch, ya que no todos los navegadores soportan fetch. En su lugar, como bien recomiendas, usaría Axios que es isomórfico para todos los navegadores

Comment: Hmm me dejaste con la duda, aunque mirando en [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=fetch) el único "importante" sería IE 11 que ya está dado de baja digamos. Incluso mirando también por [async/await](https://caniuse.com/?search=async) veo que es bastante compatible. Pero si, axios sería la opción más ajustada pero requeriría aprender un poco su uso.

Answer (score -2):

prueba con esto:

```js
    var json = '[{"dataBasic":{"id":"33","productoId":"2646"},"dataComplete":    [{"id":"2646","referencia":"102 -2119","descripcion":"Enterizo Levantacola Capellini","en_descripcion":"Enterizo Levantacola  Capellini","es_url":null,"en_url":null,"marca":"1","precioAlDetal":"89.90","precioPorPaquete":"44.49","precioPorMayor":"44.49","precioTienda":"64.40","precioMiscelaneo":"48.00","precioOutlet":null,"proveedor":"2","publicar":"Si","publicarOferta":"Si","publicarEnTienda3":null,"publicarEnTienda4":null,"publicarEnTienda5":null,"descripcion_long_es":null,"descripcion_long_en":null,"categoriaId":"21","nom_marca":"Capellini","cod_proveedor":"102","nom_proveedor":"CAPOHEIRA"}]}]';

    var obj = JSON.parse(json);
    document.getElementById("prueba").innerHTML = obj[0].dataBasic.id + ", " + obj[0].dataBasic.productoId + ", " + obj[0].dataComplete[0].id + ", " +  obj[0].dataComplete[0].referencia + ", "+ obj[0].dataComplete[0].descripcion;
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <p id="prueba"></p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Aqui leemos el JSON y despues lo nuestro en una etiqueta, si hay muchos mas datos, debes recorrerlo con `for o foreach`. Ya despues puedes armar tu tabla HTML con los estilos que quieras.

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Incluso el titulo de la pregunta lo dice `como llamar un api`, y esto nunca lo respondes, creo que esto es la parte clave de la pregunta, no como pintarlo

Comment: Si tienes el JSON tienes la API

Comment: Ese podria ser un ejemplo del json que exporta el api, no significa que ya lo tenga

Comment: puedes usar jquery ajax y en la URL colocas la URL de la api y con eso recibes las respuesta

Comment: Yo lo se, pero el OP no, en las demas respuestas si viene el ejemplo con ajax

Comment: Cual es tu problema real? por que MagdielAybar respondió tu pregunta ya que yo la entendí mal, ya con ese ejemplo debes consumir tu api sin problemas