# Mostrar datos de mi JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

No puedo mostrar los datos que obtengo en formato JSON, este es el código que utilizo.

Esta es mi función jquery, tomo los datos de un campo, los envío por post y recibo la respuesta la cual envío por la función `cargar_productos` que quiero mostrar y no puedo.

```
$('#buscar_datos').on('click', function(){

    var datos_buscar = $('#codigo').serialize();
    // alert(datos_buscar);
    //  return false;
    $.ajax({
        data: datos_buscar,
        url: 'funciones/listar_productos.php',

        type: 'post',
        success: function(datos){

                cargar_productos(datos);

        }

    });
    return false;
});
```

Aquí la función que quiero utilizar para mostrar los datos del JSON pero no entiendo como mostrarlo. Intento de esa forma pero no hay caso. Si saco un `alert` con "datos" que recibo de mi php me muestra bien el JSON.

```
function cargar_productos(datos){

$('#Salida').html(datos[0].Nombre);
}
```

El JSON es el siguiente

```
{"datos": 
[{"id":"19","Nombre":"1","Precio":"2","Categoria":"3","Codigo":"4"}]}
```

Y el php es este

```
<?php
require_once 'conexion.php';

$codigo=$_POST["codigo_producto"];

$sql="SELECT * FROM productos WHERE codigo = $codigo";



$resultado = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);

if(!$resultado){
die("Error");
}else{

while($data =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){

    $arreglo["datos"][] = array_map("utf8_encode", $data);
}

echo json_encode($arreglo);
}
mysqli_free_result($resultado);
mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

Gracias de Antemano!

Comment: No me muestra nada :(

Comment: prueba revisando que parametros te entrega en la consola con console.log(datos[0].Nombre)

Comment: Me arroja undefined , mm voy a investigar , soy nuevo en esto estoy intentando entender como funciona jaja

Comment: Hay otro comando que tiene console es console.table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisando tu inquietud y haciendo el ejemplo local puedes acceder a los elementos de la siguiente manera:

```
var jsonTest = {"datos": 
[{"id":"19","Nombre":"1","Precio":"2","Categoria":"3","Codigo":"4"}]};

console.log(jsonTest["datos"][0]["id"]);
```

Por tanto teniendo en cuenta el ejemplo anterior en tu function js seria de la sig. manera:

```
function cargar_productos(datos){
  $('#Salida').html(datos["datos"][0]["Nombre"]);
}
```

Ahora bien el problema se encontraba en la jerarquía y por tanto al revisarlo seria como te enuncio en mi ejemplo. Saludos. Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Me arroja este error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Nombre' of undefined, estoy accediendo mal a los datos seguramente, me sirvio tu ejemplo para entender muchas gracias.

Comment: La otra alternativa que puedes hacer es iterar con "For In" o con "Each" de jQuery y asi accederias como estabas haciendo inicialmente... te dejo una url relacionada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8402/como-puedo-recorrer-un-array-de-json-y-obtener-sus-valores-para-mostrarlos-en-l

Comment: Me funciono esa alternativa! Muchas Gracias , el codigo dentro de la funcion del success quedo asi finalmente.  $.each(response, function(i, datos) {
         console.log(datos[0].Nombre);
     });

Answer (score 2):

Es simple, el error está en como lo estás llamando a la variable y al json, entonces superpones los nombres y omitís un paso. Debería ser así la función `cargar_productos()`:

```
function cargar_productos(datos) {
  $('#Salida').html(datos.datos[0].Nombre);
}
```

Yo lo reenombraría para evitar confusión en la próxima vez:

```
function cargar_productos(data) {
  $('#Salida').html(data.datos[0].Nombre);
}
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Nombre' of undefined - Me arroja ese error la consola, agregue el datatype: 'Json' al ajax pensando que era el error pero tampoco funciono , no puedo acceder al atributo por alguna razon

Answer (score 1):

recibelos en una variable así:

```
var resultados = datos.d;
```

luego recién lo envías a tu función.

```
cargar_productos(resultados);
```

y los manipulas como hacias antes

```
resultados[0].Nombre
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Nombre' of undefined , intente tambien hacerlo de esa forma pero me arroja le mismo error que le comente al usuario de arriba seguire probando. Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Se puede hacer, en javascript con un `for..of..` :

```
function cargar_productos(datos){
    for (var dato of datos){
        $("#Salida").html(dato.Nombre);
    }
}
```

Si solo vas a recuperar un dato, este método funcionaría, pero en caso de que el json tenga otras propiedades hijas directas aparte de "datos", deberías implementar algo tal que así (concepto):

```
var cadena = "";
function cargar_productos(datos){
    for (var dato of datos){
       cadena+= dato.Nombre;
    }
}
 $("#Salida").html(cadena);
```

Espero que te sirva :D